# Java Applet refresh problems

Tags: java, applet, refresh

I have a Java Applet (JApplet). This Applet uses a JComponent(PanelAux) to show values and images that change periodically. But the applet doesn't refresh itself. What can I do to refresh my applet?

```
//--------------------------------------------RUN

public void run()
    while (true) {
        try {
            myThread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e){
        }    
        repaint();
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------PAINT
public void paint(Graphics g)
{     

    dim  = new Dimension(image.getWidth(this)+50,image.getHeight(this)+50);
    this.resize(dim);
    this.setMaximumSize(dim);
    this.setMinimumSize(dim);

    PanelAux panel = new PanelAux(image);   //JComponent

    add(panel);

    super.paint(g);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually call the run() method at any place of start a Thread that uses it?

Also: you definitely don't want to add new components in your `paint()` method! That is screaming for problems!

Comment: Or resize and set minimum and maximum size.

Answer (score 3):

As a general tip, the [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) article describes how you should handle repainting in either AWT or Swing.

Since you mentioned that you are using a `JApplet`, the section on "[Painting in Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#swing)" is going to be relavent here.

Specifically, with Swing, rather than overloading the `paint(Graphics g)` method, the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method should be used instead, with a call to the superclass' `paintComponent` method. Quoting from the "[Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#callbacks)" section:

> Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding
>   `paint()`.

This is because the `paint` method itself is broken down into three separate methods, overriding the `paint` method itself means that it will prevent calls to the `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren` of the current class and its ancestor classes.

Also, in order for the `run()` method to be invoked, your `JApplet` should implement `Runnable` and also have a new `Thread` invoked from somewhere within your applet. (Probably in either the `init` or `start` methods.)

**Edit:**

It also should be noted that the `paintComponent` method is going to be called anytime the screen needs to be refreshed. The `paintComponent` method will be called multiple times, so as [saua points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386583/java-applet-refresh-problems#386605), it wouldn't be a very good idea to be instantiating new objects within the `paintComponent` method itself.

Also, it seems like the design is to have a separate thread (as the applet seems to be implementing the `Runnable` interface, as implied from the presence of the `run` method), the updating of the `JComponent`'s state could take place in the `run` method itself, with a call to the `repaint` method if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should not override paint(Graphics g).

Are there any error exception throws in the applet console?